# Converting Web Site Projects to Web Application Projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5

I am in the process of converting my web site project to a web apllication project. I am following these steps:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

But when i go to build, I get namespace cannot be found errors. All my namespace code is in my App_Code folder and worked fine in my web site project.

What am I missing? Is app_code not part of web application projects?

Comment: Check the Warnings in the Errors window and post them here.

Comment: Try [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1644960.aspx/1).

Comment: You are correct. App_Code is not part of a Web Application project unless you add it to the project. In general, _nothing_ is in a web application project unless - it's in the project!